# Sum custom type as if it were a normal list F#

Tags: list, recursion, types, f#, sum

I am attempting build a function that sums the list of values that could be stored in my special type.

My type looks like this

> type intnest = INT of int | LIST of intnest list;;

I am attempting to use the code below to do my summation (I want `addup` to return type `intnest`)

```
let rec regularsum list =
   match list with
   | head :: tail -> head + regularsum tail
   | [] -> 0

let addup lt = 
    match lt with
    | INT -> lt
    | LIST ->regularsum lt
```

Can my custom type have its elements summed? and if so how should I change my code to achieve this? or what should I try next?

Comment: I think you really need to read the documentation instead of posting such a huge batch of questsions to SO - see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the best way to do this would be to use the higher order functions

```
let rec addup l =
    match l with
    |INT(_) -> l
    |LIST(li) -> 
        INT(
             li 
             |> List.map (addup) 
             |> List.fold (fun s t -> match t with |INT(a) -> s+a | _ -> failwith "bad error") 0)
```